# Creating migration history table "migration" Syntex error

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-api

I have this Error when run pipeline on bitbucket

```
./yii migrate --interactive=0
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.33-dev)
Error: syntax error, unexpected ';'
2020-03-04T05:30:03.930868636Z stdout P Creating migration history table "migration"...
```

From where this Error come and how to resolve this

Comment: do you have any migrations added in the `console/migrations` folder?

Comment: No, i did not add any migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the version issue in yii2. 2.0.32 is stable and 2.0.33 is not stable. So this issue occure